# Code performance: SQL Server Query vs C#.Net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, performance

I am writing a complex logic to calculate sales and customer bonuses. I have million of records to calculate bonuses.

I want expert opinions so that mathematical operation don't take much time to display result on web page.

So where I need to write calculation part? In SQL Server Queries (Using Stored Procedure and functions) or ASP.NET & C#.Net (Business Logic layer)?

Which one is the best practice? Processing on Database server or Processing on Application server?

Regards

Mohsin JK

Comment: if those *millions of rows* are already in a SQL Server database - process the data there! Have a stored procedure generate the results, put it in a table, and then just show the results from that table in your ASP.NET webpage.

Comment: If your calculation requires extensive use of aggregations, you can take a look on `materialized views`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have millions of records then I would suggest you to write calculation part in SQL Server as calcuations in Business Layer will significantly take more time.

Following are suggestions to improve performance -

- Write Stored Procedures
- Create Indexes to fetch records faster
- Use of temp tables if manupulation is for huge records

You can search on net to find out T-SQL other performance optimization techniques.

Comment: Agree. Additionaly, I'd suggest considering CLR functions. For complex calculations CLR might be significantly faster than plain T-SQL. Or it might not be in this particular case, so testing is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

> I have million of records to calculate bonuses

I think it is better to calculate it in database to avoid passing large amounts of data from the database to application.